# How should I code 1 css file for multpile html pages?

Tags: html, css

My home page styles work perfectly fine but when I keep coding the css for another html page, the layout breaks in the home page. For example, I have some content in the home page but I want to remove them in other pages and when I do, it breaks the layout in the main page and if I try to fix then the second page won't be the way I want. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need 1 css file for all pages. use different classes an ids and then your css will not override previous settings

Answer (score 1):

You've got to read some CSS books/guidances.

A very brief info to see (part of) what you can do:

Use different class names for differently styled sections. You can combine classes like this:

```
<div class="box headerpage">....</div>
<div class="box innerpage">....</div>
```

and in CSS it would be:

```
.box {
    // main style
}

.box.headerpage {
    // addition for header page (element with headerpage class specified
}

.box.innerpage {
    // addition for inner page (element with innerpage class specified
}
```

You can also alter the style dependant on element's ID:

```
#myDiv.headerpage {
}

#myDiv.innerpage {
}
```